# How to handle large file upload/download with REST API?

Tags: api, http, design-patterns, https, system

With several design interviews that I have been giving, this scenario has come  question that has come up often is how to handle large file upload for let's say a service like Youtube/S3 etc.

I tried looking on stack exchange and online elsewhere, but the only relevant answer I could find was the use of multipart form. But then I was wondering does the upload for large files really happens over a single API call in real-world scenarios (I am not sure on this). Can somebody explain how these uploads and downloads happen in the above-mentioned web services? Also, a follow-up question about how do the downloads happen in a 'seemingly' streaming service like youtube/ NetFlix (seemingly because data arrives in chunk here).